# \item[option]... over column edge (enumerate environment)

Tags: enumerate, itemize

I have a problem with the `\item[option]` int the `enumerate` environment: the word inside `[option]` (here Rule 1) goes over the column edge, both in on- and twocolumn mode.

This is how I coded it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,parskip,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{marvosym} 
\usepackage{lmodern} %Latin Modern fonts are a better alternative, but they unfortunately don't contain bold small caps.
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{xprintlen} %Zeigt mit dem Befehl \printlen[x][cm]{length register (z. B. \columnwidth)} die Spaltenbreite bis zur x Nachkommastelle an.

\usepackage[svgnames,table,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{floatflt,epsfig}  % Um Text und Abb nebeneinander zu positionieren

\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum} % Um Text und Abb nebeneinander zu positionieren

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{siunitx}  
\usepackage{framed, color}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{realboxes}
\sisetup{locale = DE} 
\usepackage[intlimits]{empheq}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{theorem} 
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{array}

%%% Pagestyle
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} %eigener Seitenstil
\fancyhf{} %alle Kopf- und Fußzeilenfelder bereinigen
\fancyhead[L]{{\sffamily{\bfseries Biotechnologie:} Amino acids, peptides, proteins and enzymes}}
\fancyhead[R]{{\sffamily{\bfseries WiSe 2019/2020}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{{\sffamily{\bfseries \thepage}}}
\fancyfoot[R]{{\sffamily{\bfseries Henri Lila}}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

% LaTeX colores: https://latexcolor.com
\definecolor{airforceblue}{rgb}{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}
\definecolor{babypink}{rgb}{0.96, 0.76, 0.76}
\definecolor{asparagus}{rgb}{0.53, 0.66, 0.42}
\definecolor{babyblueeyes}{rgb}{0.63, 0.79, 0.95}
\definecolor{blizzardblue}{rgb}{0.67, 0.9, 0.93}
\definecolor{arsenic}{rgb}{0.23, 0.27, 0.29}
\definecolor{darkcerulean}{rgb}{0.03, 0.27, 0.49}


% Caption
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bf-parens}{\textcolor{darkcerulean}{\textbf{Fig. #2: }}}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,font={small},labelformat=bf-parens,labelsep=none,format=plain]{caption} % https://ctan.kako-dev.de/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{table}}

\newcommand{\scap}[1]{\textcolor{darkcerulean}{\textbf{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item[{\bfseries Rule 1}] 
    Rotations of the Fischer projection by 180$^\circ$ in either direction doe not change the absolute configuration at the chiral center (see fig. \ref{rule} a).\\
    After a 90$^\circ$ or 270$^\circ$ rotation, bonds located above the paper plane before the rotation are beneath the paper plane after the rotation and vice versa, thus resulting in an inverted stereochemical configuration which is only realizable through a bond dissociation and a following rebound.
    \item[{\bfseries Rule 2}] Rotation of three substitutes on the chiral center in either direction, keeping the remaining substitutes in place, does not change the absolute configuration at the chiral center (see fig. \ref{rule} b).
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

When using the

```
\begin{enumerate}[align=left, font=\bfseries]
    \item[{\bfseries Rule 1}] 
    Rotations of the Fischer projection by 180$^\circ$ in either direction doe not change the absolute configuration at the chiral center (see fig. \ref{rule} a).\\
    After a 90$^\circ$ or 270$^\circ$ rotation, bonds located above the paper plane before the rotation are beneath the paper plane after the rotation and vice versa, thus resulting in an inverted stereochemical configuration which is only realizable through a bond dissociation and a following rebound.
    \item[{\bfseries Rule 2}] Rotation of three substitutes on the chiral center in either direction, keeping the remaining substitutes in place, does not change the absolute configuration at the chiral center (see fig. \ref{rule} b).
\end{enumerate}
```

This is how it looks:
[image]
(Better, but still not good).
Thanks for any help, cheers

Comment: well you will have to change the enumerate layout then. Use the enumitem package to adjust the spacing or the alignment of the label.

Comment: With package `enumitem`, try using $`\begin{enumerate[align=left, font=\bfseries]`.

Comment: @Bernard is edited my post, there you can see, it still doesn't look the way its supposed to look.

Comment: @HenriLila We need a *complete* (though minimal) compilable document in order to help well, something that can be copy/pasted and is ready for experiments. You may want to try `leftmargin=3cm` (or whatever value you prefer) but I haven't tested it, for this very reason.

Comment: For a two document layout, and items with long labels,  consider use the default `description` environment instead of a tuned  `enumerate` non enumerated.

Comment: I now almost get the solution: with `\begin{enumerate}[{\textbf{Rule}} 1]` it looks like I want it, only that I can't get the number printed in bold. I tryed `\begin{enumerate}[font=\bfseries,{\textbf{Rule}} 1]` but this didn't work. Anyone knows how to make everything bodl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `enumitem`. You'll just have to type `\item` without any optional argument. B.t.w., don't load *both* enumitem and enumerate.

*Unrelated*: you shouldn't load `epsfig` – it is only a wrapper for `graphicx` to ensure compatibility for old documents (cf. *l2tabu*).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,parskip,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{lmodern} %Latin Modern fonts are a better alternative, but they unfortunately don't contain bold small caps.
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage{textgreek}
%\usepackage{here}
%\usepackage{xprintlen} %Zeigt mit dem Befehl \printlen[x][cm]{length register (z. B. \columnwidth)} die Spaltenbreite bis zur x Nachkommastelle an.

\usepackage[svgnames,table,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum} % Um Text und Abb nebeneinander zu positionieren

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{framed, color}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{realboxes}
\sisetup{locale = DE}
\usepackage[intlimits]{empheq}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{array}

%%% Pagestyle
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} %eigener Seitenstil
\fancyhf{} %alle Kopf- und Fußzeilenfelder bereinigen
\fancyhead[L]{{\sffamily{\bfseries Biotechnologie:} Amino acids, peptides, proteins and enzymes}}
\fancyhead[R]{{\sffamily{\bfseries WiSe 2019/2020}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{{\sffamily{\bfseries \thepage}}}
\fancyfoot[R]{{\sffamily{\bfseries Henri Lila}}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

% LaTeX colores: https://latexcolor.com
\definecolor{airforceblue}{rgb}{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}
\definecolor{babypink}{rgb}{0.96, 0.76, 0.76}
\definecolor{asparagus}{rgb}{0.53, 0.66, 0.42}
\definecolor{babyblueeyes}{rgb}{0.63, 0.79, 0.95}
\definecolor{blizzardblue}{rgb}{0.67, 0.9, 0.93}
\definecolor{arsenic}{rgb}{0.23, 0.27, 0.29}
\definecolor{darkcerulean}{rgb}{0.03, 0.27, 0.49}


% Caption
\usepackage{caption} %
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bf-parens}{\textcolor{darkcerulean}{\textbf{Fig. #2: }}} %https://ctan.kako-dev.de/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf
\captionsetup{margin=0pt,font={small},labelformat=bf-parens,labelsep=none,format=plain}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{table}}

\newcommand{\scap}[1]{\textcolor{darkcerulean}{\textbf{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=Rule \arabic*\space, font = \bfseries, wide=0pt, widest, itemindent=-3pt, leftmargin=*]
    \item%
     Rotations of the Fischer projection by 180$^\circ$ in either direction doe not change the absolute configuration at the chiral center (see fig. \ref{rule} a).\\
    After a 90$^\circ$ or 270$^\circ$ rotation, bonds located above the paper plane before the rotation are beneath the paper plane after the rotation and vice versa, thus resulting in an inverted stereochemical configuration which is only realizable through a bond dissociation and a following rebound.
    \item% 
    Rotation of three substitutes on the chiral center in either direction, keeping the remaining substitutes in place, does not change the absolute configuration at the chiral center (see fig. \ref{rule} b).
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that works perfectly!